# Ubuntu not able to detect USB device

Tags: ubuntu, usb

I am trying to connect a FTDI programmer USB to program esp32. However, the system is not detecting the connection.
Following commands don't show any logs at all during connecting and remvoing the device.

```
tail -F /var/log/syslog
```

and

```
dmesg
```

Please suggest the solution. The cable is in perfect condition.

Comment: did you have a look at documentation? Do you have drivers installed, etc? check this to start with http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man4/uftdi.4freebsd.html

Comment: @Bart I have all drivers installed as described in online sources.